# Double login issue after logout after following documentation

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to follow the Expo documentation for the Authentication process: https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/#example-authentication-context .

I have basically copy-pasted everything in the documentation.

The login flow works as intended, with the context provided as the documentation says -- the only change I've made is for the Sign-In function. The Sign-in function calls an API, retrieve the JSON and then save the whole data into the session:

```
    return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            signIn: async (username, password) => {
                await AuthResp(username, password).then((promise) => {
                    if (promise) {
                        const sessionDecode = JSON.parse(promise)
                        console.log(sessionDecode.usr_type)

                        switch (sessionDecode.usr_type) {
                            case "usr":
                                router.replace({pathname: `/user`})
                                break;
                            case "admin":'
                                router.replace({pathname: `/admin`})
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                })
            },

            signOut: () => {
                setSession(null)
            },

            session,
            isLoading,
        }}>
        {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);

const AuthResp = async(username, password) => {
    console.log(`Trying login for ${username}:${password}...`)
    let userSessionJSON = null

    try {
        const knackPromise = await fetch(`APILINK`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "email": username,
                "password": password
            })
        })

        await knackPromise.json().then(async (promise) => {
            console.log(promise.session)
            if (promise) {
                if (promise.errors && promise.errors[0]) {
                    alert(promise.errors[0].message)
                } else {
                    const userSessionData = {
                        //sessionData
                    }
                    userSessionJSON = JSON.stringify(userSessionData)
                    await SecureStore.setItemAsync("session", userSessionJSON).then( () => {
                        setSession(userSessionJSON)
                    })
                }
            }
        });

        setSession(userSessionJSON)
        return userSessionJSON

    } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

This works as intended, but I have some issues when the user decides to log-out. When the log-out button is pressed, the session is deleted as intended. However, when the user then decide to log-in again, the session is always "null" the first time and it requires to login again, then it redirect as normal. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'm quite sure this is some async function I've messed up.

What am I doing wrong?

(please ignore the multiple "setSession" i've put in the code, it was just for testing)

**EDIT.** I have tried to remove all the the stuff from "signIn", leaving it as simple as possible:

```
signIn: async (username, password) => {
                setSession("abc")
                router.replace({pathname: `/user`})
            }
```

But the issue still persists. Notice the "null" after the first login, and the "abc" after the second login.
[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you are mixing `async/await` with `.then()/.catch()`.  That rarely ends up working out the way one intends.  Go with one or with the other, not both.  Technically it is doable....but you really have to be comfortable with how "Asynchronous Code Execution" works in JavaScript.

> I strongly encourage all of my friends (and make it a requirement of all of my coworkers) to watch the video JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts multiple times: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts&t=1s
>
> Especially the parts about Synchronous and Asynchronous code execution (time links are in the video description).

With your edit, the `signIn()` code should no longer be marked as `async` because you are not making any asynchronous calls.  [Are there any warnings or errors in your console?  If so, work to resolve them all]

My suspicion is that your main issue is with the invocation of asynchronous code and trying to change routes via an asynchronous method.